# How to print out all upper case string in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

The issues I am running to is that it does not print out anything.

Is there something wrong with my if statement? because it printed out the whole txt. file when I did not add the if statement.

```
fname = input('Enter the file name: ')

try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except:
       print('File cannot be opened:', fname)
       exit()

for line in fhand:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.isupper():
        print(line)
```

The file contains like HTML, CSS, I/O and SQL, and it should prints out all those strings.

Comment: `if line = line.isupper()` is assigning something to `line`, not checking to see if it is all uppercase (the difference between `=` and `==`).

Comment: I found out my issues now, open() does not give me to read() the file, I need read() method to be able to operate with the file.

Answer (score 0):

To check for equality, use `==`. However, I'm pretty sure you are looking for `isupper` by itself, not checking it for equality. `isupper` returns a boolean, which can be checked by your `if` statement:

```
for line in fhand:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.isupper():
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement uses `=` which is used for assignment, not for comparison. Instead use `==`. Besides of which, `string.isupper()` is a boolean in itself, so you will be comparing a string to a boolean, which will not yield the result you want.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, the = was a mistake.  I did not mean to type it in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` function instead:

```
for line in filter(str.isupper, fhand):
    print(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be more idiomatic to open the file using a with statement, rather than a try/except as it handles closing the file once the object reaches end of scope. 
https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

```
with open(path_to_file, 'r') as fileobj:
    for line in fileobj:
        if line.strip().isupper():
            print(line)
```

--UPDATE--

From the link above for the individual who down voted this answer:

> It is good practice to use the **with** keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its
>   suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point. Using
>   **with** is also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks

Also

```
line.strip().isupper()
```

is perfectly valid.

[line.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) returns a copy of the line object, which is of type str (string) with whitespaces removed and [.isupper()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) called on that object returns a boolean.

Example

```
line = '  AES '
print(line.strip().isupper())
```

Will return True and

```
line = ' aes '
print(line.strip().isupper())
```

Will return False

--UPDATE--

For completeness following @Tomothy32 comment

```
import os

path_to_file = "/path/to/file"

if os.path.isfile(path_to_file):
    with open(path_to_file, 'r') as fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            if line.strip().isupper():
                print(line)
else:
    print("Please pass valid path to file")
    exit()
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but I'm guessing it's because you stated `with` is a direct replace for `try`-`except`, which it's not. (`with` is a replacement for `try`-`finally`.) The `try`-`except` here was used to check if the file existed.

Comment: Thank you, that's understandable, I'll ensure full checks going forward :) I thought path_to_file was enough to suggest that path validation had/should have been done prior to the with/open combo :/